# Using MoveIt to solve COM based Inverse Kinematic

Tags: ros, moveit, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users

Is it possible to use MoveIt to solve inverse kinematic of a manipulator based on position of arm center of mass (COM) in task space?

For example, consider a double inverted pendulum. Can MoveIt give us joint angles that sets the total center of mass of robot (double inverted pendulum) to specific feasible point in workspace?

Thanks for your considerations

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244854/using-moveit-to-solve-com-based-inverse-kinematic/) by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Masoud,

This is currently not possible from MoveIt! but as the COM and mass can be specified for each link in the URDF and are available on the parameter server, it should be possible. A package that does forward calculation of the COM can be found [here](https://github.com/ahornung/hrl_kinematics), but I haven't used it so I don't know how well it works.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0